# On an html page, how do I get PHP to use multi-lines?

Tags: php, html

This code on an html page comes in as one line.  Why isn't backslash n working?

```
    <?php
        $text1 =  "I don't understand how this works!  \nHow the hell do I get this thing to use \nmulti lines in PHP???!!!";
        echo $text1;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is multiline. HTML simply ignores line breaks (See the page's source code to see it). You probably want to use `<br>` to line break in HTML.

```
<?php
$text_to_echo =
    "I don't understand how this works!<br>\n
How the hell do I get this thing to use <br>\n
multi lines in PHP???!!!";
echo $text_to_echo;
```

Comment: @dwstein: No, but it would have worked if you had displayed it as a text file. `header("Content-type: text/plain");`

Answer (score 0):

Use [nl2br()](http://in.php.net/nl2br) function like this.

```
<?php
        $text1 =  nl2br("I don't understand how this works!  \nHow the hell do I get this thing to use \nmulti lines in PHP???!!!");
        echo $text1;
    ?>
```